# JAVA - Parsing XML file is not storing data properly

Tags: java

I'm parsing an XML file fine, apart from it's not saving the first data found and only the second(last)

Here is the file:

```html
package main;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import main.advertise.Advert;
import main.advertise.guilds.Guild;
import main.advertise.server.Server;

public class Servers {

 //private Server[] servers;
 //private Guild[] guilds;
 
 private ArrayList<Server> servers = new ArrayList<Server>();
 private ArrayList<Guild> guilds =  new ArrayList<Guild>();
 

 
 @SuppressWarnings("null")
 public void init() {
  
  Server server = new Server("", "", "", "", new String[] {}, new String[] {}, 0, 0, 0);
  Guild guild = new Guild("", "", "", "", new String[] {}, 0);
  
     try {
      

  

      File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/NULL/Desktop/Adverts.xml");
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      
 
  
      NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("advertisement");
      
      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

       Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
         
       System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
         
       if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Server Name - " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("servername").item(0).getTextContent());
        server.setServerName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("servername").item(0).getTextContent());
        server.setDiscordLink(eElement.getElementsByTagName("discordlink").item(0).getTextContent());
        server.setOwnerId(eElement.getElementsByTagName("ownerid").item(0).getTextContent());
        server.setLogoUrl(eElement.getElementsByTagName("logourl").item(0).getTextContent());
        
      
        
           NodeList features = doc.getElementsByTagName("feature");

           String[] featureList = new String[features.getLength()];

           for (int i = 0; i < features.getLength(); i++) {
             Node node = features.item(i);
             featureList[i]=features.item(i).getTextContent();
             System.out.println(features.item(i).getTextContent() + " - new");
           }
           server.setServerFeatures(featureList);
        
        

         
            NodeList images = doc.getElementsByTagName("image");

            String[] namesArray = new String[images.getLength()];

            for (int i = 0; i < images.getLength(); i++) {
              Node node = images.item(i);
              namesArray[i]=images.item(i).getTextContent();
              System.out.println(images.item(i).getTextContent() + " - new");
            }
         server.setServerImages(namesArray);
         
         
            
         
         
         
            guild.setGuildId(eElement.getElementsByTagName("id").item(0).getTextContent());
            guild.setGuildName(eElement.getElementsByTagName("guildname").item(0).getTextContent());
            System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("guildname").item(0).getTextContent());
            guild.setAdvertiseChannel(eElement.getElementsByTagName("advertchannel").item(0).getTextContent());
            guild.setCommandChannel(eElement.getElementsByTagName("commandchannel").item(0).getTextContent());
            
               NodeList users = doc.getElementsByTagName("user");

               String[] namessArray = new String[users.getLength()];

               for (int i = 0; i < users.getLength(); i++) {
                 Node node = users.item(i);
                 namessArray[i]=users.item(i).getTextContent();
                 System.out.println(users.item(i).getTextContent() + " - new users");
               }
            guild.setAuthorisedUsers(namessArray);
            
            
            guild.setAdvertisementDelay(Integer.parseInt(eElement.getElementsByTagName("delay").item(0).getTextContent()));
            //guilds[tempp] = guild;
            guilds.add(guild);
         servers.add(server);
         Advert advert = new Advert(guild, server);
         Main.servers.add(advert);
         
       }

      }

 
      
         } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
         }
     System.out.println("Size: ----------------- " + servers.size());
  for(int i = 0; i < servers.size(); i++) {
   if(guilds.get(i) == null)
    return;
   Advert v = new Advert(guilds.get(i), servers.get(i), servers.get(i).getServerName());
   if(!Main.servers.contains(v)) {
  //Main.servers.add(new Advert(guilds.get(i), servers.get(i), servers.get(i).getServerName()));
   }
  }
  System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(0).getServer().getServerName());
  System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(0).getGuild().getGuildName());
  System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(1).getServer().getServerName());
  System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(1).getGuild().getGuildName());
  
       }

     }
```

Here is the XML file:

```html
<advertisements>

<advertisement>
<server>
<servername>Zenith</servername>
<discordlink>http://zenithps.org</discordlink>
<ownerid>304558905306906624</ownerid>
<logourl>http://zenithps.org/Zenith%20Logo.png</logourl>
<feature>Feature1</feature>
<feature>Feature2</feature>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Zenith Logo.png</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Description Hovers.gif</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Launcher.png</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Upgrade.gif</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Pet.png</image>
</server>
<guild>
<id>642406906580828181</id>
<guildname>Guild</guildname>
<advertchannel>658936539803418624</advertchannel>
<commandchannel>658936539803418624</commandchannel>
<user>304558905306906624</user>
<delay>25000</delay>
</guild>
</advertisement>


<advertisement>
<server>
<servername>Test Server</servername>
<discordlink>http://zenithps.org</discordlink>
<ownerid>304558905306906624</ownerid>
<logourl>http://zenithps.org/Zenith%20Logo.png</logourl>
<feature>Feature1</feature>
<feature>Feature2</feature>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Zenith Logo.png</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Description Hovers.gif</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Launcher.png</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Upgrade.gif</image>
<image>C:/Users/NULL/Pictures/Pet.png</image>
</server>
<guild>
<id>6424069110828181</id>
<guildname>Test Guild</guildname>
<advertchannel>658936539803418624</advertchannel>
<commandchannel>658936539803418624</commandchannel>
<user>304558905306906624</user>
<delay>25000</delay>
</guild>
</advertisement>
</advertisements>
```

When printing

```
System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(0).getServer().getServerName());
System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(0).getGuild().getGuildName());
System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(1).getServer().getServerName());
System.out.println("    "+Main.servers.get(1).getGuild().getGuildName());
```

I am getting the response
    Test Server
    Test Guild
    Test Server
    Test Guild

However, this should be
    Zenith
    Guild
    Test Server
    Test Guild

It prints the Zenith and the Guild whilst parsing the file using:

```
System.out.println("Server Name - " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("servername").item(0).getTextContent());

System.out.println(eElement.getElementsByTagName("guildname").item(0).getTextContent());
```

But it isn't storing it properly. I've tried moving things around but cannot seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Here both Main.servers.get(0) and Main.servers.get(1) points to same instance. Instead of creating a `new Server/Guild` instance, for each server-element only one instance is modified again and again, so the `Server/Guild` will have the last element's data.
Please move the initialization Inside for loop and it should work fine. 
**Please move**

```
Server server = new Server("", "", "", "", new String[] {}, new String[] {}, 0, 0, 0);
Guild guild = new Guild("", "", "", "", new String[] {}, 0);
```

**Inside**

```
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
```